# Cell color changing in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office

I am using a Windows application for exporting a data table to Excel. It's working. Now I want to give some color for particular text in the cell. How shall I do this?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

For text:

```
[RangeObject].Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
```

For cell background

```
[RangeObject].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
```

Comment: You can avoid the clutter of `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator` by using `Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbRed` instead.

Comment: How can I sort by cell color?

Comment: Using this on Cells property erases borders. Using this on Range property with two indexers causes a COM exception.

Comment: Why is it ColorTranslator.ToOle but not ColorTranslator.ToWin32?

Answer (score 17):

Note: This assumes that you will declare constants for row and column indexes named `COLUMN_HEADING_ROW`, `FIRST_COL`, and `LAST_COL`, and that `_xlSheet` is the name of the `ExcelSheet` (using `Microsoft.Interop.Excel`)

First, define the range:

```
var columnHeadingsRange = _xlSheet.Range[
    _xlSheet.Cells[COLUMN_HEADING_ROW, FIRST_COL],
    _xlSheet.Cells[COLUMN_HEADING_ROW, LAST_COL]];
```

Then, set the background color of that range:

```
columnHeadingsRange.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbSkyBlue;
```

Finally, set the font color:

```
columnHeadingsRange.Font.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbWhite;
```

And here's the code combined:

```
var columnHeadingsRange = _xlSheet.Range[
    _xlSheet.Cells[COLUMN_HEADING_ROW, FIRST_COL],
    _xlSheet.Cells[COLUMN_HEADING_ROW, LAST_COL]];

columnHeadingsRange.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbSkyBlue;

columnHeadingsRange.Font.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbWhite;
```

Answer (score 2):

For C#, using the Workbook class (which implements the Workbook Interface) can provide lots of tools for coloring.  I used Workbook (templateWorkbook in below example) as follows to set colors:

```
var copyFormating = templateWorkbook.Worksheets[sheetName].Cells[9,0].GetStyle();
copyFormating.ForegroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gold;
copyFormating.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
copyFormating.HorizontalAlignment = TextAlignmentType.Center;
```