# Excel-clearing or adding format for inserted rows-C#

Tags: c#

I am inserting rows in an Excel template from C#. Here is my issue : the row I start my insert with has a solid yellow fill and I need my inserted rows to be white. I am using Interop and have tried a few things but have been unsuccessful. I use a for loop to send these rows, below is my code.

```
if (((CheckBox)srcAddOnPanel.Controls["chkAddItem" + AddRow]).Checked) //.Checked == false)
  {
    worksheet.Rows[StartAddOn].Insert();
    worksheet.Cells[StartAddOn, "D"].value = srcAddOnPanel.Controls["txtQtyAddOn" + AddRow].Text;
    worksheet.Cells[StartAddOn, "E"].value = srcAddOnPanel.Controls["txtProductNameAddOn" + AddRow].Text;
    worksheet.Cells[StartAddOn, "F"].value = srcAddOnPanel.Controls["txtListPriceAddOn" + AddRow].Text;
    worksheet.Cells[StartAddOn, "G"].value = srcAddOnPanel.Controls["txtMaxDiscountAddOn" + AddRow].Text;
    worksheet.Cells[StartAddOn++, "H"].value = srcAddOnPanel.Controls["txtProposedPriceAddOn" + AddRow].Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `Range.Interior.Color` [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.interior_members.aspx)

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452417/cell-color-changing-in-excel-using-c-sharp) stackoverflow question

Comment: Ok, this does work,,,somewhat. The only issue I will have is: I wont be able to apply an actual set of cells because what I am sending to excel is dynamic controls so I never know where they are going to land. I use a for loop to send them.

Comment: @CamlCase You can add your actual example code if you want me to have a look at it, but I think at some point you have to convert from abstract controls to concrete cell ranges. So I can't really see your problem there.