# How to make look and feel of custom Excel sheet made using c# similar to the one downloaded from SharePoint

Tags: c#, excel, console-application, export-to-excel, sharepoint-2016

I have made an excel download console application using csom to download the list data from SharePoint. I want this excel to look like below SharePoint Excel:
  [image: SP Excel]

Currently my custom excel looks like below:

[image: Custom Excel]

Can anyone please help me with the formatting code for my custom excel? I need formatting for alternate rows which can be of any length.

**Note**: The above SharePoint Excel is the SharePoint OOTB Export to Excel functionality for All items of the list.

Comment: What library are you using to export your excel? also please put the code you are using to export excel

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library...Why do you need my export to excel code??? I just need to do the formatting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cell color changing In Excel using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452417/cell-color-changing-in-excel-using-c-sharp)

Comment: I need formatting for alternate rows.

Comment: Just use a `for` loop and check whether the index is odd or even, and change the color accordingly

Comment: @munmunpoddar I need your export excel code because you havent mentioned what type of collection you are using to export in excel datatable ot anyting else

Comment: It is also necessary to provide minimal,compelete & verfiable example -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Lucifer I have already mentioned that I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library. by this library i had made my object  `Excel.Application xlSamp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();`

Comment: @Rafalon I am not getting how t use it for odd and even rows...I will appreciate if you can help me with the code.

Comment: I edited and undeleted my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2452525/7831383).

The following should work, with `workSheet` being your Excel worksheet:

```
// define your colors (header, odd rows, even rows)
var HeaderColor = XlRgbColor.rgbAliceBlue;
var EvenRowColor = XlRgbColor.rgbLightBlue;
var OddRowColor = XlRgbColor.rgbWhite;

// get the column/row count
int ColumnCount = _;
int RowCount = _;

// set the header color
var firstHeaderCell = workSheet.Cells[1, 1];
var lastHeaderCell = workSheet.Cells[1, ColumnCount];
workSheet.Range[firstHeaderCell, lastHeaderCell].Interior.Color = HeaderColor;

// loop through all the rows
for(int i=2; i<=RowCount; i++)
{
    var currentColor = i%2 == 1 ? OddRowColor : EvenRowColor;

    var firstRowCell = workSheet.Cells[i, 1];
    var lastRowCell = workSheet.Cells[i, ColumnCount];
    // set row color based on i being even or odd
    workSheet.Range[firstRowCell, lastRowCell].Interior.Color = currentColor;
}
```

Note that you can choose your colors using [`XlRgbColor` enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlrgbcolor-enumeration-excel).

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It helped !!!