# How to change the background color of an Excel sheet cell in C#

Tags: c#, excel

How can I change the background color of an Excel sheet cell with C#?

[image]

Comment: dup? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452417/cell-color-changing-in-excel-using-c-sharp

Comment: Well, reference `System.Drawing` into your project?!? https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNRPb.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it that way:

```
xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 1].Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbRed;
```

But don't forget to declare the right using:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

And I declared the following variables

```
Excel.Application xlApplication;
Excel.Workbook xlWoorkbook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet;

xlApplication = new Excel.Application();
xlWoorkbook = xlApplication.Workbooks.Add();
xlWorksheet = xlWoorkbook.Worksheets[1];
```

Hopefully that works for you too!